# Border positioning through CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the orange border on the blue border (only the orange border should move). I have seen this many times on websites but I could not get it without removing the padding of the parent div.

```css
nav.navbar.navbar-light {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #97B6D0;
  /*box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #5286B1;*/
}
nav.navbar.navbar-light > ul.nav.navbar-nav > li.nav-item.active > a.nav-link {
  color: #5286B1;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F7A411;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="img/Xeeva_only_xeeva_sign_h_38 copy.png" width="43" height="38" alt="" />
    </a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Opportunities</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Here is the code on JS fiddle:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anandgeetey/mpnLjr04/1/).

Comment: Either remove all paddings and margins from parents OR use a pseudo selector to control positioning instead of border

Comment: Huh? Why can I only see a code block in the published question, but a stack snippet in the editor preview?

Comment: @Oriol ya, that is weird. Was just trying to figure that out myself.

Comment: @APAD1 It seems it's due to the `babel: false` flag.

Comment: Folks: I tried to edit it to make it clear but before me @APAD1 had already edited it so my edits were unpublished. I am working on it again to make it clear for the viewers. Is JS Fiddle working for you?

Comment: @Oriol thanks, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the bottom padding from the entire list, knocking the list items down a pixel and increasing the bottom padding above the orange border. I altered your css to be the following:

```
/* Navigation*/

nav.navbar.navbar-light{
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #97B6D0;
    padding-bottom:0;                   /*ADDED LINE*/
    /*box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #5286B1;*/
}
.navbar-nav .nav-item {
  margin-bottom:-1px;                   /*ADDED LINE*/
}
nav.navbar.navbar-light > ul.nav.navbar-nav > li.nav-item.active > a.nav-link {
    color: #5286B1;
    padding-bottom:15px;                /*ADDED LINE*/
    border-bottom:2px solid #F7A411;
}
```

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mpnLjr04/2/